# How to add date/calender within a card in compose?

Tags: android, kotlin, datepicker, android-jetpack-compose

I am trying to add a date/calender-picker to my card. I have already managed to create a card as seen in the image above but I am not sure how to populate it with the datepicker? Whenever I click it, its prompt to open a window called DatePickerDialog but I want it to already appear with the dates within the card itself, as seen in the image. Any advice on how to do so? Appreciate the feedback!

https://gyazo.com/32481eed83fa534f28841ec373565e3c

Datepicker code:

```
@Composable
fun DatePicker2() {
    val context = LocalContext.current
    val calendar = Calendar.getInstance()

    var selectedDateText by remember { mutableStateOf("") }

// Fetching current year, month and day
    val year = calendar[Calendar.YEAR]
    val month = calendar[Calendar.MONTH]
    val dayOfMonth = calendar[Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH]

    val datePicker = DatePickerDialog(
        context,
        { _: DatePicker, selectedYear: Int, selectedMonth: Int, selectedDayOfMonth: Int ->
            selectedDateText = "$selectedDayOfMonth/${selectedMonth + 1}/$selectedYear"
        }, year, month, dayOfMonth
    )
    Text(
        text = if (selectedDateText.isNotEmpty()) {
            "Selected date is $selectedDateText"
        } else {
            "Please pick a date"
        }
    )

    Button(
        onClick = {
            datePicker.show()
        }
    ) {
        Text(text = "Choose birthday date")
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `androidx.compose.material3`.**DatePicker** along with a `androidx.compose.material3`.**BottomSheet** to achieve the desired behavior.

Here's how you can do it:

```kotlin
@Composable
fun BottomSheetDatePicker(
    state: DatePickerState,
    sheetState: SheetState = rememberModalBottomSheetState(),
    onDismissRequest: () -> Unit
) {
    ModalBottomSheet(
        onDismissRequest = onDismissRequest,
        sheetState = sheetState,
        dragHandle = { BottomSheetDefaults.DragHandle() },
    ) {
        DatePicker(
            state = state,
            showModeToggle = false,
            title = null,
            headline = null
        )
    }
}
```

This is an example to how to use it

```
@Composable
fun Content() {

    val datePickerState = rememberDatePickerState()
    var sheetState by remember{ mutableStateOf(false) }
    val selectedDate = Instant.ofEpochMilli(datePickerState.selectedDateMillis ?: 0)
        .atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault())
        .toLocalDate()

    Column {
        Text(
            text = if (datePickerState.selectedDateMillis != null)
                "Selected date is $selectedDate"
            else
                "Please pick a date"
        )

        Button(
            onClick = { sheetState = true }
        ) { Text(text = "Choose birthday date") }
    }

    if (sheetState)
        BottomSheetDatePicker(
            state = datePickerState,
            onDismissRequest = { sheetState = false }
        )
}
```

Adjust the code according to your specific requirements.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Yes that was exactly what I was looking for, will try to adjust it to my requirements! Appreciate the help and feedback! @Al-Taie